# Show location of coordinates on google maps using Python

Tags: python, google-maps

I wrote a code for data science and I got some coordinates that I want to plot on google maps. These are the coordinates, and all of these coordinates are in capitol city of Serbia called Belgrade.

```
        X          Y
 20.657460  44.490140
 20.510760  44.652443
 20.510540  44.884460
 20.471758  44.788613
 20.359841  44.742405
 20.472120  44.763520
 20.610525  44.676290
```

How can I plot these data on google maps so that I can see locations of these coordinates on google maps?
I tried with matplotlib, and with some Santdex tutorials and with `pygmaps`but I failed. I could not intall `pygmaps`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [gmplot](https://pypi.org/project/gmplot/) to plot data with Google Maps.

To do so, install with `pip install gmplot`.

Then, the code should look like :

```py
from gmplot import gmplot

# Initialize the map at a given point
gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(37.766956, -122.438481, 13)

# Add a marker
gmap.marker(37.770776, -122.461689, 'cornflowerblue')

# Draw map into HTML file
gmap.draw("my_map.html")
```

You can see [gmplot repo](https://github.com/vgm64/gmplot) to see how to use it.

Comment: Ok, but how can I see my plot?
I ran your code, it does not have errors, but I cant see map

Comment: In my example, a map should appear when you open the generated HTML file into your favorite browser, having a plot on Lily Pond in San Francisco

Comment: I understand, But I do not get any HTML file

Comment: I don't understand, I'm currently running `python plot.py` and file `my_map.html` is generated

Comment: Is the code you posted full code?
I copy/paste your code to my idle and when I run it, nothing happens

Comment: I think that it is due to the file path, try with an absolute path to be sure to find the right place the HTML file is generated in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192279/discussion-between-z4cco-and-aleksandar).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to generate a hmtl file with the code which displays the map on a browser but my plotted points on the map are not displaying

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33924245)